# How to count number of characters(including spaces) before the third column in unstructured data?

Tags: r, regex, text-processing

I have unstructured data that look like this:

```
x <- c("24-March-2017     text1       874874455221112  Text text text10",  
"25-March-2017         text2       54654656TEXT      Text text 11", 
"24-March-2017    text3         874874455221112 Text text text 12")
```

I would like to count number of characters including spaces before the 3rd column. For example in the first line I would like to count everthying before the number 874874455221112.

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(x, ''), function(l){r <- rle(l == ' '); r$lengths[r$values][2]})` or maybe `sapply(gregexpr('\\s+', x), function(m){attr(m, 'match.length')[2]})`

Comment: alistaire- thx, tried this but it only counts number of spaces. I would like to count number of spaces and characters from the beginning of the line until the 3rd column.

Comment: Oops, misunderstood. Just `sapply(gregexpr('\\S+', x), \`[\`, 3) - 1` should do it.

Comment: Thx, worked great.

Comment: How many questions about this data are you going to ask before you try something yourself?

Comment: @ Rich Scriven- good question... I'm using it as a learning opportunity to expand my knowledge in R and learn from this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gregexpr` is the base R regex function that returns information about the position of multiple matches in strings. To extract them you'd use `regmatches`, but since `gregexpr` returns the index of the first character of each match, you can simply search for groups of non-space characters `\\S+`, select the third index, and subtract one to get the number of preceding characters:

```
sapply(gregexpr('\\S+', x), `[`, 3) - 1
#> [1] 30 34 31
```

Comment: You can do better by using repetitions and capture groups directly in the regex. No need for an extra R call to split and extract the result.

Comment: "Better" how? The regex here is simpler, and I'm not convinced it's slower, as subsetting—even with `sapply`—and subtraction are very fast.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `stringr` library:

```
library(stringr)
str_length(str_extract(x,"^(\\S+\\s+){2}"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some one-liners that all use `regexpr` in the base of R.  No packages are used.

**1)** Typically the more assumptions that you can make the shorter the answer. 
 Here we get quite a compact answer by assuming that when you write text in the question you mean. words.  In that case the third field is the first field that both starts with a digit and is prefaced by space so look for a whitespace character ("`\\s"`) followed by a digit (`"\\d"`).

```
regexpr("\\s\\d", x)
```

giving:

```
[1] 30 34 31
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 2 2 2
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

**2)** If the word assumption is not the case so that the second field can start with a digit then we can readily reduce it to the above case by changing the first character of the 2nd field to a non-digit, `x` say, and then doing the above. In the code below `"\\S"` matches any non-whitespace character. This gives the same answer as (1) except it also works in the case that the second field starts with a digit.

```
regexpr("\\s\\d", sub("\\s\\S", " x", x))
```

**3)** Another way is to match the first two fields and the space beyond them. `regexpr` will return the required character length in the `"match.length"` attribute.

```
attr(regexpr("^(\\S+\\s+){2}", x), "match.length")
## [1] 30 34 31
```

**Note:** If the question is in partial answer to reading the 4 fields then that can be done directly by inserting a comma or other special character between fields and then reading the result using `read.table`. I have assumed that the 3rd field is all digits so TEXT is supposed to be in the 4th field but if it is supposed to be in the 3rd field then replace `"\\d"` with `"\\S"` in `pat`.

```
pat <- "^(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s*(.*)"
read.table(text = sub(pat, "\\1,\\2,\\3,\\4", x), sep = ",", colClasses = "character")
```

giving:

```
             V1    V2              V3                     V4
1 24-March-2017 text1 874874455221112       Text text text10
2 25-March-2017 text2        54654656 TEXT      Text text 11
3 24-March-2017 text3 874874455221112      Text text text 12
```